# panel angular2 with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, panel

I am planning on building a website with angular2. I tried to use bootstrap for my css framework but can't get the panel to work. I want a panel that is collapsable to be mobile friendly. It says it's needing jquery for the javascript in bootstrap. But i know that jquery and angular2 do not go well together so i'm wondering if i realy need to install jquery into my project or if there is another way to get a panel for my angular2 website.

I dont not HAVE to use bootstrap if there is a better css framework for doing the job.

Thanks!

Comment: ng-bootstrap integrates bootstrap 4 with angular, and doesn't need jquery. http://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ng-booststrap from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started and either add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in your `index.html` or download boostrap version 4 and include it in your `styleUrls`.

Comment: Thank you it works! And then use the collapsable in the header i gues? I'll accept your awnser